# way to, way of, or way in

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

> There's no other way in handling terrorism.
> There's no other way to handle terrorism.
> There's no other way of handling terrorism.

I think all of them sounds good except the second one. The second one sounds incorrect. Am I correct?

Comment: I find the second example correct and natural. The first example sounds a little strange, but with a different word order, it sounds natural enough:  
"In handling terrorism, there is no other way." I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

*Way* (in the sense of "method") subcategorises for  "to" infinitive clause, or *of* + an "-ing" clause, so your 2 and 3 are both equally good.

It doesn't take an "in" argument, so the only interpretation of your 1 is

> There's no other way (of doing something unspecified) in (the area of) handling terrorism.

There might be contexts where this makes sense, but I haven't come up with any. (I nearly can, with a comma after "way").

Comment: There are alternatives to X in handling normal crime, but there is no other way in handling terrorism.